# Allowing a user to mount a samba share from fstab

Tags: linux, samba, mount, cifs

I am unable to get `mount.cifs` to respect the `user` flag passed to mount. The entry in `/etc/fstab` is

```
//10.0.1.205/rm /home/robert/remote/rm cifs user,uid=robert,gid=users,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,credentials=/etc/samba/navision,rw,noauto 0 0
```

but when executing

```
robert@rm:~/remote> mount rm
```

I receive

```
mount error(1): Operation not permitted
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g.man mount.cifs)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [`mount.cifs`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) has to be `setuid` to allow normal users to mount shares.

> It is possible to set the mode for `mount.cifs` to `setuid` root to
>   allow non-root users to mount shares to directories for which they
>   have write permission.

Comment: Not anymore: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/657900

Comment: That is only for Ubuntu - Debian has changed its behavior back to setting mount.cifs setuid (see [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576713) and [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576314)) based on upstream.  In any case, it was still possible to set it setuid, just not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Do NOT name a drive volume "rm" under Linux.  You are asking for disaster.

Comment: Tell that to my system administrator team. Unix users are created by initials. Guess what my user is :-)

Comment: *LOL* @Robert Munteanu

Answer (score 1):

This is the format I think you want to use-it looks like maybe you're using the wrong user deceleration in the command pasted above

```
//192.168.44.100/share_name /path_to/mount_point cifs username=server_user,password=server_password,_netdev,uid=client_username,gid=users 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having trouble mounting folders shared by LanDrive (Android), or mount points folders and files with accented characters.

sudo mount -t cifs '//SERVER_IP_HERE/Shared_Folder' /mnt/MountPoint_Here -o port=Port_Here,iocharset=utf8,user=USER,password=
PASSWORD,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777